# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView setSeparatorInset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

The following in viewWillAppear

```
    [SYPTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Works fine on iOS 7 but on 6.1 it raised the exception :

```
    NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView setSeparatorInset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

My purpose is to remove the cell border.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `separatorInset` property is available on `UITableView` from iOS 7.0 and that's why you get the exception on iOS 6.1.

From the code you posted it looks like you want to remove the default inset introduced in iOS 7. Such inset is not present in iOS 6, so you only have to remove the inset in iOS 7.

You can check whether the table view responds to `setSeparatorInset:` doing

```
if ([SVPTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [SYPTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Comment: so what is the iOS 6.1 alternative ?

Comment: @Petronnel, I support both. My question was what is "something reasonable"

Comment: There's no such thing as a separator inset in iOS 6. If your purpose is to remove the default inset introduced in iOS 7, you can just do nothing in iOS 6, since by defaults there's no inset.

Comment: My purpose was to remove the cell border. without this line the cell border will show up.

Comment: That's the wrong method for removing the cell border, read the documentation. You want instead to set the `separatorStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`

Comment: [SYPTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];  removed the sperator only in iOS 7, in 6.1 it didn't

Comment: By the way, what's `SYPTableView`?

Comment: @Petronella UITableView*

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40488/discussion-between-mike-and-gabriele-petronella)

Comment: Please follow the conventions and use lowercase names for variables. That being said, this question (why does `setSeparatorInset:` crash on iOS 6) has an answer. If you have a different question (why setting `separatorStyle` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` is not working), you should post it separately.

Comment: what is the work around to be done in iOS 6 to look it similar to iOS 7. i.e, suppose if I have separator inset 64 points from left, how can i have one in iOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in ios 6 etc use the following

```
 SEL selector;
 selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"setSeparatorInset:");
 if([table respondsToSelector:selector])
{
    @try {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSMethodSignature *aSignature;
            NSInvocation *anInvocation;
            aSignature=[table methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
            anInvocation=[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:aSignature];
            [anInvocation setSelector:selector];
            [anInvocation setTarget:table];
            UIEdgeInsets temp=UIEdgeInsetsZero;
            [anInvocation setArgument:&temp atIndex:2];
            [anInvocation invoke];
        });


    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EXCEPTION WHILE CALLING Separator inset => %@",[exception userInfo]);
    }
    @finally {

    }
}
```